# Geoplugin returning nothing Javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Its so simple yet somehow I've done something wrong.

http://www.geoplugin.com/quickstart#how_to_geo-localize_your_visitors

The code in the above site works fine, it knows exactly where I am yet when I copy over the code to my webpage it doesn't work.

In the head tag:

```
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In a div tag:

```
<script language="Javascript">document.write("function geoplugin_region() { return '"+ geoplugin_region()+"'; }");</script>
```

Returns:

function geoplugin_region() { return ''; }

The relevant part being '' in between the quotations a region should be displayed but its not.
(Both my webpage and the geoplugin were opened in internet explorer)

Any ideas?

For testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script language="Javascript">document.write("function geoplugin_region() { return '"+ geoplugin_region()+"'; }");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

So when others test the code on their computers it works fine

When I open other people's pages that contains the geoplugin code it works fine

But if I open a website that is located in my harddrive it doesn't work (both work and home computers)

Any ideas?

**ANSWERED**

EI (9) security settings were causing the problem I just had to convert the html to a hta and it works fine (I can't actually change the security settings for IE here at work so that was not an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upload you sources code as a html file to my  server,and it return a true place where I live.

So,I think the geoplugin may use the XMLHttpRequest technology of AJAX.
Also,you can click http://hanasite.com/jscon/demo.html to checking.
Hope it can help you solve you problem. :)

(because of low reputation so I can't upload a screenshot:()

Comment: Ok so your site works fine for me (tested both at work and home) But I still don't understand what I have to do to get it work. I tried doing some research on that xmlhttprequest and my brain fizzled. Could you elaborate a little more on what I'm supposed to be doing?

Comment: Btw I also copied your code to adobe dreamweaver and it didn't work (tested both at work and home)

Comment: If you want to test local,you may have to install php environment on your PC,then input the link like http://localhost/xx.html on your browser.(xx.html can include the above sources code).

Comment: Solved turned out IE was causing the problem with some of its security settings, converted the html to a hta (which has more lenient security settings here at work) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code I wrote. It's really simple and it works perfectly (tested).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Your IP is: <span id="ip"></span></li>
        <li>Your city is: <span id="city"></span></li>
        <li>Your region is: <span id="region"></span></li>
        <li>Your areaCode is: <span id="areaCode"></span></li>
        <li>Your dma code is: <span id="dmaCode"></span></li>
        <li>Your latitude is: <span id="latitude"></span></li>
        <li>Your longitude is: <span id="longitude"></span></li>
        <li>Your currencyCode is: <span id="currencyCode"></span></li>
        <li>Your currencySymbol is: <span id="currencySymbol"></span></li>
    </ul>
<script>
 var ip = geoplugin_request();
 var city = geoplugin_city();
 var region = geoplugin_region();
 var areaCode = geoplugin_areaCode();
 var dmaCode = geoplugin_dmaCode();
 var latitude = geoplugin_latitude();
 var longitude = geoplugin_longitude();
 var currencyCode = geoplugin_currencyCode();
 var currencySymbol = geoplugin_currencySymbol();
 document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = ip;
 document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = city;
 document.getElementById('region').innerHTML = region;
 document.getElementById('areaCode').innerHTML = areaCode;
 document.getElementById('dmaCode').innerHTML = dmaCode;
 document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
 document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = longitude;
 document.getElementById('currencyCode').innerHTML = currencyCode;
 document.getElementById('currencySymbol').innerHTML = currencySymbol;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an updated version with all the stuff working, regards!

Comment: why image? StackOverflow perfectly capable of displaying code

Comment: because I'm prevent from sending code. Whenever I do there is a message about bad formatting or multiple request asking if I'm human and it annoy me.

Comment: if you paste your code, select it and press button "code sample", editor will indent it by 4 space and in preview block you see it shown in gray block.

Comment: I just tested your code and it did return the ip, so I decided to test everything with your code and it returned the request + status just fine but city, region, areaCode, dmaCode, countryCode, countryName, continentCode, latitude, and longitute returned nothing. Does this hint at something more specific?

Comment: I updated the code using the same technique I presented in the original answer and it works great.

Comment: Hmm tried your code out and I can see the ip but still can't see the others :S Is there something I have to install to get this to work? Currently testing it at work will test it later at home (to check whether this is a security/network issue)

Comment: It is strange indeed because I make sure to test my code before updating it. Are you able to see yourself there; http://www.utrace.de/ ?

Comment: Yep it knows exactly where I am.

Comment: I think it must be becuase of this computer, the code works from other external sites but not when I run it from  this computer (or the one at home). But I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you using a local server?